# Converting data with commas to variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, csv

I have a row of a lines that is like this, these are the lines of html output of a php code that comes from a search.

here is the browser output page source (not the server source)

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta`enter code here` content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>my page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <title>My Page</title>
      <form name="myform" action="systemmonitor.php" method="GET">
        <div align="center">My page<br>
          <br>
          <input name="sea1" placeholder="customtext" size="25" type="text"> <br>
          <br>
          <input name="sea2" placeholder="customtext" size="25" type="text"> <br>
          <br>
          <input name="sea" value="submit" type="submit"><br>
          <br> 
data00,data01,data02,data03, , , and so on
data10,data11,data12,data13, , , and so on
data20,data21,data22,data23, , , and so on
(and so on in rows)
<br>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is the browser server source (php)

```
    **<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta`enter code here` content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>my page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <title>My Page</title>
          <form name="myform" action="systemmonitor.php" method="GET">
            <div align="center">My page<br>
              <br>
              <input name="sea1" placeholder="customtext" size="25" type="text"> <br>
              <br>
              <input name="sea2" placeholder="customtext" size="25" type="text"> <br>
              <br>
              <input name="sea" value="submit" type="submit"><br>
              <br> 
    <?php
$searchthis = $_GET["sea1"];
$matches = array();

$handle = @fopen("sources.csv", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE)
            $matches[] = $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

//show results:
$myString = implode( ', ', $matches );
print_r($myString);
?><br>
    <br>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Now, in the real page where is data0,data1,data2... is a php code that make this stuff from the html forms above, now the php output i dont what to see as is, but i want to convert to variables, and show only the variables where i want to, something likes this its ok:

```
var parsed[0][0]=data00;
var parsed[0][1]=data01;
var parsed[0][2]=data02;
var parsed[0][3]=data03;
var parsed[1][0]=data10;
```

0,X (X is the number of the colume)
1,X (X is the number of the row)

 
and then i show only the data where I want.
for example i will put this code somewhere in the page:

```
document.write(parsed[0][3]);
```

the data00 data01 is just a custom data that php will make from before.

how I can do this convert?

Comment: Your numbering in your first snippet makes no sense! Why is the first row `(01, 02, 03)` but the second row `(11, 22, 33)`?

Comment: is just a custom data, nothing else, where is 11 for examble will be ''house'' or anything else. thx.

Comment: You cannot have variables that start with digits in JS.

Comment: Is the PHP code your own? Can you modify it? Is the search page hosted on the same domain as the page you want to run this javascript on?

Comment: @Eric i can modify the PHP code, its mine, yes its all hosted on the same domain, and same page..

Comment: Show us the PHP then!

Comment: @Eric here it is, see the update question.

Comment: Ok, final question - Why do you need the javascript? Why can't you use `<?php echo $matches[0]; ?>

Comment: @Eric becouse this code will show only the data by lines, not be lines&columes of the csv-style text output, if i can search with php with lines&columes then i dont javascript, what ever is php or js, its ok for me. thx. i dont know php well, this php was from a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
// the string containing the data
var externalData = 'one, two, three\n'
                 + 'four, five, six\n'
                 + 'seven, eight, nine';

// split the string into rows, and split each row into cells
var parsed = externalData.split('\n').map(function(row) {
    return row.split(', ');
});

console.log(parsed[0][1]);  // 'two'
```

Comment: this makes ''one,two,three four,five,six seven,eight,nine''
but i want to read only ''three'' (for example) or only seven?

Comment: @user2670708: Have a proper look at the code. `parsed[0][1]` returns the second value of the first row (`two`), `three` is the *third* value of the first row, so you need `parsed[0][2]`, etc. If you don't know how arrays work, I recommend to read a tutorial: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html.

Comment: yes but one two three have to be the real data that come from the page.
how i can see my custom data instead of 'one' or 'two' ?

Comment: @user2670708: The value of `externalData` is just an *example*. You apply the same procedure on your string/data. Don't you see the resemblance of the example and your data?

Comment: i know that is example, but i dont know how to put my data in there, because the data is coming automatically from a php code and the format is specific, (one,two,three,and so on).

Comment: Mean that if my php output was = **'one, two, three\n' + 'four, five, six\n' + 'seven, eight, nine';** ...was ok, but i comes just on **one,two,three and so one**, how can i put this ((php-output)) on the javascript code? if am say it well.

Comment: @user2670708: If you are using Ajax to get the data, then your data is in the response text. You don't really provide any information about how you get the data, so it's difficult to give any suggestion.

Comment: @user2670708: I would suggest to put an HTML around the output and give it an ID. Then you just read the elements content with `var data = document.getElementById('my_data').innerHTML;`. If the rows are really denoted through `<br>` elements, then you have to split on `<br>` instead of `\n`. Or you could wrap each line in an HTML element (like a span) give it a class and use `getElementsByTag` to get a list of those so that you can iterate over them and extract the data. If would recommend to read a bit about JavaScript and DOM traversal/manipulation (Google).